# Advanced Search and Remove in special Matrix

Tags: matlab

I have this matrix

```
X= [2 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 250;
    3 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 250;
    2 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 250;
    3 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 250;
    4 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 250;
    3 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 250;
    2 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 250;
    4 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 250;
    3 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 250;
    3 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 400]
```

I need to do three different sequence things in this matrix:

1- Search in this matrix to the following sequence 1 1 0 0 0 and write those rows that have this characteristic in new matrix (like row 1).

2- Use the matrix that generate in the first step and remove from it to  the rows that have the same number in the same digits (like row 1,3,7) but at the same time keep only one row of each one (in the case of row 1,3,7 keep row 1 and remove other rows) .

3- use the matrix that generate in the second step and remove from this matrix any row that have following sequence 1 1 1 (like row 8) and put the other rows in this matrix in new matrix.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generate matrix have special charactristics](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39486469/generate-matrix-have-special-charactristics)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
%Step-1
% Converting the matrix into a string, appending a semi-colon for similarity and removing the brackets from the string
req=mat2str(X);      req(end)=';'       ;   req=req(2:end);
% Searching the sequence: 1 1 0 0 0
sp1=strfind(req, '1 1 0 0 0');
% Storing those rows of X in req matrix which contain the sequence
req=X(unique(ceil([sp1]/(size(req,2)/size(X,1)))),:);


%Step-2
req= unique(req,'rows');

%Step-3
% Converting the matrix into a string, appending a semi-colon for similarity and removing the brackets from the string
reqtemp=mat2str(req);   reqtemp(end)=';'  ;    reqtemp=reqtemp(2:end);
% Searching the sequence: 1 1 1
sp1=strfind(reqtemp, '1 1 1');
% Removing those rows which contain the sequence
req(unique(ceil([sp1]/(size(reqtemp,2)/size(req,1)))),:)=[];
```